# Hide teamviewer icon from top bar

Tags: settings

I want to hide team viewer icon from the top status bar. But, I still want teamviewer to keep running in background.

I have already checked `Automatically minimize local team panel` in advanced settings

[image]

Comment: How did you get icons showing up there?

Answer (score 1):

I think, that's an application specific choice not to hide on panel. Personally I prefer a non-hiding icon for such a potentially suspicious application.

Answer (score 1):

You can fix the indicator icon to match the elementary indicators style:
https://github.com/mank319/elementaryPlus/issues/335